# How to detect url from google ad link using php

Tags: php

How do i detect a user visiting from the `google ad link`. And if the user is from google url i need to perform some php function.

```
function google_ad(){
    blahblah
}
```

Comment: What do you mean `google ad link`?

Comment: I think you are looking for HTTP REFERRER

Comment: @AmalMurali google's banner ad

Comment: can you please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18670497/how-to-detect-url-from-google-ad-link-using-php/18670541#18670541

Answer (score 0):

One option is to try to check $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']. But some browsers may not send it.

Another option is just to add some GET param to your URL when you register it at Google (http://yourdomain.com?ga=1).

Answer (score 0):

can you please used this code :

```
<?php
if($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]=="url") {
    // Some Code
}
?>
```

**$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]**

The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.

[Check On PHP Website](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

If it's for analysis purposes, you can use [Goole Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) and [Google Webmaster](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/) Tools.

They both complement each other, and do pretty much want you want to accomplish with your script